# Failed to install the Extension Pack /home/user/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.0.4.vbox-extpack

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install the virtualbox extension pack (Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.0.4) and I get the following error.

`Failed to install the Extension Pack 
/home/user/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.0.4.vbox-extpack.`

`Failed to load the main module ('/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxPuelMain.so'): VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND - /usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxPuelMain.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK16RTCRestArrayBase9baseCloneEv.`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Check your version of VirtualBox, I had v5 attempting to install Extension Pack v6 which caused the error.  Upgrading VirtualBox to v6 fixed it.
Or install the Extensions pack version for your installed version of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4):

Error `NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)` appears also in case if you try to install VirtualBox extension pack being a usual user. It could not be considered as an answer to actual question, but could be useful for users who search for `Failed to install the Extension Pack` error message which is present in this case too.

In this case

- you need to run your VirtualBox with `sudo` privileges from terminal:

  ```
  sudo virtualbox
  ```
- Virtualbox could offer you to download and install extension pack

But if you ignored that, you could do it the next way:

- install extension pack that matching your virtualbox version using

  **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Extensions**
- close and reopen VirtualBox using a regular user's account

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds
2. Look up your virtualbox build number
3. Look for your host or distribution
4. Download the extension pack which is under your build and install.